# Django login doesn't work, how can fix it?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have login form in my project. When I write correct username and password it doesn't post my request and my browser area looks like that: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=EukLSCRC5B25iBrDXqVsQ7iyF2FUUhgrldri2MIrb3IM8f4dMngo66tciJkmfNYt&username=admin&password=123
(Because my username:admin, pass:123)

I tried change "form method" POST to post in html login template but doesn't work. And I deleted csrf_token but actually doesn't work again.

## forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = "Username")
    password = forms.CharField(label = "Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

## views.py

```
def loginUser(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {

        "form": form

    }

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")

        user = authenticate(username = username, password=password)

        if user is None:
            messages.info(request,"Username or Password is incorrect! Try again.")
            return render(request,"login.html", context)

        messages.success(request,"Login successful! Welcome honey.")
        login(request,user)
        return redirect("index")

    return render(request,"login.html",context)
```

## urls.py

```
app_name = "user"

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register, name ="register"),
    path('login/',views.loginUser, name ="login"),
    path('logout/',views.logoutUser, name ="logout"),

]
```

## login.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">

        <h3>Login</h3>
        <hr>
        <form method = "post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Sign In</button>

            </form>


    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock  %}
```

Browser area shows: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=EukLSCRC5B25iBrDXqVsQ7iyF2FUUhgrldri2MIrb3IM8f4dMngo66tciJkmfNYt&username=admin&password=123
(Because my username:admin, pass:123)

Comment: `if user is not None: login(request, user)` can you add this part before your `if user is none `

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working. Because problem is not user auth or correct password.

Comment: method="post" should be without spaces...

Comment: I suggest to read how the `contrib.auth` does it and tweak it to get what you want, the form: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L178
the view: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L67

Answer (score -1):

Dont use form.cleaned_data ,
Use:

```
request.POST.get("username","")
```

Same for password!

Answer (score -1):

Can you add action in form ? Your form dont have an action.

```
<form method = "post" action="{% url 'user:login' %}>
```